# how can I simulate the MMA7361L?

Tags: simulation, accelerometer, capacitive, model

I wanted to know if there is a simulator that could include the model of the capcitive accelerometer NXP MMA7361L, and if there is a tool-box in matlab that could include it or should I find the transfert fonction first to simulate in matlab ? 
Thanks in advence.

Comment: Does the data sheet refer to any .model statements?

Comment: No, I guess that it doesn't.